# HTML5 layout and footer error

Tags: css, html, footer

I am new to the world of HTML5 and I am trying to build a layout to give me a better understanding on how i can move on from HTML4. I have currently built a layout but wanted to check:

1. If my code is written correctly (any tips or advice would be really appreciated, as first time I am writing in HTML5 so want to make sure im doing things right)
2. trying to fix the footer to sit at the bottom of the page, overlapping the sidebar and section2 slightly but at present it is showing across the middle of the page.
3. I have noticed when viewing the site in Firefox and using Firebug the site does not show up in the exact size that I have defined in the CSS, so would like to understand why this is.

The following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BrightBees Layout</title>
<link href="styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id ="container">   
    <header>
        <h1>This my Header</h1>
        <nav><h2>My Navigation Bar<h2></nav>
    </header>
    <div id="banners"><h2>My Banners<h2></div>
    <aside id="sidebar"><h2>My SideBar<h2></aside>
    <section id="content"><h2>This is my section1</h2></section>
    <section id="list"><h2>This is my section2</h2></section>
</div>
<footer>
        <h3>This is my footer</h3>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
background:#FFF;
}

#container {
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
width:960px;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

header  {
margin:0;
padding:0px;
text-align:center;
height:166px;
}

nav {
height:65px;
text-align:center;
background:#CCC;
}

#banners {
margin:0;
height:253px;
background:#01AEF0;
text-align:center;
}

#sidebar {
height:600px;
width:310px;
background:#ec8400;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}

#content {
height:300px;
width:650px;
background:#CCC;
float:right;
text-align:center;
}

#list {
height:300px;
width:650px;
background:#01AEEF;
float:right;
text-align:center;
}

footer {
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
height:167px;
background:#efefef;
z-index:-1px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks in advance for looking at this, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `z-index:-1px` definitely doesn't comply

Answer (score 0):

give height to the 'container' in css file should be in 'px'...

example

`#container {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width:960px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    height: 600px
}`

it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

some steps to to at first:
Remove default browser margin and padding.

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Remove *margin:0* and *padding:0* from .header, .footer and #banner.

use meta viewport tag to make it more responsive:

```
<head>
    <title>BrightBees Layout</title>
    <link href="styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of ID's, they're too specific. Leave ID's for JS.

See here for the difference between ID's and classes:
https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: Thanks guys for this, really appreciate it. Some helpful tips.

The footer now sits under the sidebar/section2, how do i get the footer to overlap so it starts in the background of sidebar/section by around 40px.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following to my footer tag in the css file and this overlaps behind the sidebar/section that i required.

```
margin-top: -80px;
```

Thanks guys for looking at this for me, really appreciate it.